# multi querying to get the same result from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables `product_sold` , `product_received`.  I have common fields in both the tables 
product_sold table

`product_id | reference     | sold_date
 1          | For designing | 2017-02-01
 2          | dshdshf       | 2017-02-05`

product_received Table

`product_id | reference        | received_date
 4          | stock updation   | 2017-03-01
 2          | stock review     | 2017-03-05
 1          | Stocks shipment  | 2017-03-06`

I want to get the result like

`Product Code | Reference        | Date 
 19mm Alimin  |  Stocks shipment | 2017-03-06
 19mm Alimin  |  For Designing   | 2017-02-01
 Alu Tape SC  |  Stock review    | 2017-03-06
 Alu Tape SC  |  dshdshf         | 2017-02-05
 9mm Sheet Pl |  Stock updation  | 2017-03-01`

Product Name is in my product table which i have to join with these two tables. i tried to execute the query with `mysqli_multi_query`, but did not work.

My product table

`product_id  | product_name 
  1          | 19mm Alimin
  2          | Alu Tape SC
  3          | 10.5 mm
  4          | 9mm Sheet Pl`

Comment: please show us the structure of your product table as well.

Comment: the column Product Code is unclear where that data is comming from.

Comment: i have edited my post above with product table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two queries are possible to get your expected results.
You need to JOIN and UNION ALL to combine the two queries.

```
SELECT 
    product.product_name AS 'Product Code'
 ,  product_sold.reference AS 'Reference'
 ,  product_sold.sold_date AS 'Date'
FROM 
 product
INNER JOIN 
 product_sold
ON
 product.product_id = product_sold.product_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    product.product_name AS 'Product Code'
 ,  product_received.reference AS 'Reference'
 ,  product_received.received_date AS 'Date'
FROM 
 product
INNER JOIN 
 product_received
ON
 product.product_id = product_received.product_id
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    product.product_name AS 'Product Code'
 ,  product_sold.reference AS 'Reference'
 ,  product_sold.sold_date AS 'Date'
FROM 
 product
INNER JOIN 
 product_sold
USING product_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    product.product_name AS 'Product Code'
 ,  product_received.reference AS 'Reference'
 ,  product_received.received_date AS 'Date'
FROM 
 product
INNER JOIN 
 product_received
USING product_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had 2 more fields in other table also. I have joined it successfully. Thank you very much. 1st query worked perfectly for me.

Comment: i am trying to add column name `Details`, in that if it is from `product_sold` table, it should display as `Sales` or if it is from `product_received`, it has to display `Purchase`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT product_id, reference, sold_date as date  FROM product_sold
UNION
SELECT product_id, reference, received_date as date FROM product_received
```

or use UNION ALL to get duplicate values too.

In response to your edit, if you want to do it with the join included:

```
SELECT `product`.`product_name`, a.* FROM 
    (SELECT product_id, reference, sold_date as date  FROM product_sold
    UNION
    SELECT product_id, reference, received_date as date FROM product_received) AS a
INNER JOIN product ON `product`.`product_id` = a.`product_id`;
```